# Parallelism using Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pool

I try to copy the images from a source folder to a destination folder by splitting by a value.
When I run this code I get the following error. What to do?

It seems like there is something wrong with the parallelism.

Code:

```py
import os
import shutil
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager, Lock, cpu_count, freeze_support # freeze support makes safe process creations
import pandas as pd
import platform

# Define paths:
# NOTE: Change these for 'your' machine.
external_hard_disk_path_windows = r"E:\Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts_DATA\DIME images"
external_destination_source_folder_windows = r"E:\Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts_DATA"
external_hard_disk_path_linux = "/run/media/magnusjsc/T7/Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts_DATA/DIME images/"
external_destination_source_folder_linux = "/run/media/magnusjsc/T7/Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts_DATA/"
csv_file_path = r"..\DIME billeder.csv"

# File extensions to look for (tuple)
extensions_to_look_for = ('.jpg')

# Search thesaurus
thesaurus_label = ['dime.find.coin']
# Define a batch size for copying images
BATCH_SIZE = 50
# Create a Manager to handle shared variables - parallel handling
manager = Manager()
processed_images = manager.Value('i', 0)
total_images = manager.Value('i', 0)
# Lock mechanism
lock = Lock()

# Copy images from source folder to destination folder in batches
def copy_images(filename_destination_pairs, source_directory):
    batch = []
    for filename, destination_dir in filename_destination_pairs:
        source_path = os.path.join(source_directory, filename)
        destination_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, filename)
        batch.append((source_path, destination_path))
    try:
        # Batch copy the images
        for source_path, destination_path in batch:
            shutil.copy2(source_path, destination_path) 
        # Update in parallel the number of processed images using the lock
        with lock:
            processed_images.value += len(batch)
            # Save the value to a file for resuming if stopped midthrough
            with open('processed_images.txt', 'w') as file: # w = write
                file.write(str(processed_images.value))
        # Print the current progress and remaining images
        remaining_images = total_images.value - processed_images.value
        print(f'Processed: {processed_images.value}/{total_images.value}, Remaining: {remaining_images}', flush=True, end='\r')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error copying images: {str(e)}', flush=True, end='\r')

# Process and sort images
def process_and_sort_images(df, source_directory, destination_directory_coin, destination_directory_others):
    # Create a pool of worker processes based on CPU cores
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    print(f'Number of CPU cores: {cpu_count()} : The number of workers is created accordingly')
    try:
        # Set to keep track of processed filenames
        processed_filesnames = set() 
        # Check if the source directory exists
        if not os.path.exists(source_directory):
            print(f'Source directory {source_directory} does not exist')
            return
        # Check if the destination folders exist. Else create them
        for destination_dir in (destination_directory_coin, destination_directory_others):
            if not os.path.exists(destination_dir):
                os.makedirs(destination_dir)
        # Create a list of filenames to copy
        filenames_to_copy = []
        destination_dir = None
        # Iterate through and prepare images for copying
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            filename = row['filnavn']
            thesaurus = row['thesaurus']
            if any(thesaurus.startswith(label) for label in thesaurus_label) and filename in os.listdir(source_directory):
                destination_dir = destination_directory_coin
            else:
                destination_dir = destination_directory_others
            # Append the filename and destination to the batch as a tuple
            filenames_to_copy.append((filename, destination_dir))
            # If the batch size is reached, copy the batch
            if len(filenames_to_copy) == BATCH_SIZE:
                # Parallel execution using map which maps a function to input
                pool.map_async(copy_images, [(filenames_to_copy, source_directory)])
                processed_images.value += len(filenames_to_copy)
                filenames_to_copy = []  # Reset the list for the next batch
        # Copy any remaining files in the (last) batch
        if filenames_to_copy:
            # Maps a function to input
            pool.map_async(copy_images, [(filenames_to_copy, source_directory)])
            processed_images.value += len(filenames_to_copy)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {str(e)}')
    finally:
        # Close the pool of workers
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

def main():
# Load the CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, delimiter=';')
    total_images.value = df.shape[0]
    if not os.path.exists(csv_file_path):
        print(f'CSV file "{csv_file_path}" not found.')
        return

    # Path of images and destination of coin images based on OS.
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        print('Running windows.')
        source_directory = external_hard_disk_path_windows
        destination_directory_coin = os.path.join(external_destination_source_folder_windows, "coin")
        destination_directory_others = os.path.join(external_destination_source_folder_windows, "others")
    else:
        print('Running Linux.')
        source_directory = external_hard_disk_path_linux
        destination_directory_coin = os.path.join(external_destination_source_folder_linux, "coin")
        destination_directory_others = os.path.join(external_destination_source_folder_linux, "others")

    # Check if there are images that have already been processed
    if os.path.exists('../processed_images.txt'):
        with open('../processed_images.txt', 'r') as file: # r = read
            last_processed_index = int(file.read())
    if last_processed_index > 0:
        # Skip the processed images in the DataFrame
        df = df.iloc[last_processed_index:]
        # Update the manager to the number of alreadt processed images
        processed_images.value = last_processed_index
        print(f'Number of processed images already: {last_processed_index}')
    # Lets go....
    process_and_sort_images(df, source_directory, destination_directory_coin, destination_directory_others)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Allow: Processes in parallel on Windows
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()    
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 291, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "c:\Users\carls\Desktop\Pre-spec project 9th semester\Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts\python_scripts\image_sorter_coin_others.py", line 27, in <module>
    manager = Manager()
              ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 57, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 563, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\carls\Desktop\Pre-spec project 9th semester\Classification-and-3D-reconstruction-of-archaeological-artifacts\python_scripts\image_sorter_coin_others.py", line 27, in <module>
    manager = Manager()
              ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 57, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 567, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 321, in _recv_bytes
    waitres = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Just a heads up that you are doing work outside of `main()`. for example `manager = Manager()`. I would recommend not doing anything other than declaring variables and methods outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.